# IntelliJ Scala "Package" not in "New" menu

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and would like to create a new Scala Package. In all of the [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/13.0/creating-packages.pdf) that I find online I see that I am supposed to select "Package" from the "New" menu. However, my "New" menu does not include "Package" as an option.

[image: Package is nowhere to be found]

How can I add "Package" to this list or otherwise add a package to my Scala application?

Also as a side note, I am developing Scala applications and as such I would like for primarily Scala related templates to appear in this list as opposed to the menagerie or irrelevant templates that currently presents itself. How can I edit the list of templates that appears in this menu?

Comment: This might mean that the folder you selected and right-clicked is not identified as a Scala *source root* by IntelliJ. You can define Scala source roots manually under "Project Structure", or using the build tool of your choice (SBT, Gradle...) and reloading the IntelliJ project. If this needs further clarification - please add more information to the post: show the folder tree, explain how you set up the project, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by taking the following steps:

1. Making sure to install both the Scala and SBT plugins. (I was missing the SBT plugin)
2. Copying all the source files (`*.scala`) into a temporary location
3. Deleting the project.
4. Creating a new project with the same structure and copying the source files into their proper location.

Now "Package" appears in the menu (and full syntax hilighting now works, which was the reason why I wanted to fix this in the first place). Note that simply installing the SBT plugin (step 1) was not sufficient in fix this problem.

Maybe it was a bug.

Comment: AFAIR if you have Scala plugin, SBT is obsolete. Also you don't have to delete everything, just `.idea` directory. Just make sure you use *new project from sources* instead of clicking *recent project* to have a control over settings.

Comment: The SBT IDEA plugin may be obsolete, SBT is certainly not.